# how can i determin that the input is checked in controller?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, checkbox, laravel-8

there is a controller to save orders and  there is some checkbox inputs .

i try to explain that if that input is checked ... some code must be run. but in any conditional mode

`$debatorprice`, `$payment` and `$kalaf` are returned null

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     if ($request['image']){

         $file = $request['image'];
         $imgname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
         $this->ImageUploader($file, '/upload/orders/');
     }else{
         $imgname=null;
     }

     $payment="";
     $debatorprice="";
        if ($request->has('paymentstatus')){
            $payment=1;
            $debatorprice=0;
        }else{
            $payment=0;
            $totalprice=$request->totalprice;
            $beforeprice=$request->beforeprice;
            $debatorprice=$totalprice-$beforeprice;
        }
        $kalaf='';
        if ($request->has('kalaf')){
            $kalaf=1;
        }else{
            $kalaf=0;
        }

        offlineorder::create([

            'ProductType'=>$request->producttype,
            'OtherProduct'=>$request->otherproduct,
            'CustomerName'=>$request->customername,
            'CorporateName'=>$request->corporatename,
            'Phone'=>$request->phone,
            'Width'=>$request->width,
            'Height'=>$request->height,
            'Model'=>$request->model,
            'Material'=>$request->material,
            'Color'=>$request->color,
            'Count'=>$request->count,
            'Kalaf'=>$request->kalaf,
            'Image'=>$imgname,
            'Text'=>$request->text,
            'Description'=>$request->description,
            'TotalPrice'=>$request->totalprice,
            'BeforePrice'=>$request->beforeprice,
            'PaymentStatus'=>$payment,
            'DebtorPrice'=>$debatorprice,
            'SKU'=>$request->sku,
            'ChapStatus'=>0,
            'DesignStatus'=>0,
            'View'=>0,
            'Link'=>0,

        ]);

        session()->flash('add_order','سفارش شما با موفقیت ثبت شد');
        return back();
    }
```

i try `if ($request->paymentstatus==null)` but it didn't work too

Comment: For one, you are not using `$kalaf` in `'Kalaf'=>$request->kalaf,`. Do your checkboxes have values? Did you `dd($request)` to see if they are actually sent in the request?!

Comment: instead of null condition try with isset($request->paymentstatus)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$request->filled('input')
```

This will check if the input is present and filled.

If you only wanna check if the input is present you can use

```
$request->has('input')
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present

Answer (score 0):

check with empty() method
it will check empty as well as if isset

```
if(empty($request->paymentstatus)){}
```

Answer (score 0):

check with isset function like this:

```
if(!isset($request->paymentstatus)){}
```